# Multipart data form fail sending from alamofire swift to web api

Tags: c#, swift, asp.net-web-api2, multipartform-data, alamofire

I'm working with swift 2 on client and alamofire tor sending image and parameters to my server that is web api 2 C# 
the client code

```
// init paramters Dictionary
var parameters = [
     "OwnerUserId": UserId!,
     "GroupId": "nb",
     "GroupName": groupName!
] 
// example image data
let image = UIImage(named: "IMG_0801.PNG")
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)
// CREATE AND SEND REQUEST ----------
let urlRequest = urlRequestWithComponents("http://xyz.azurewebsites.net:80/api/files", parameters: parameters, imageData: imageData!)

Alamofire.upload(urlRequest.0, data: urlRequest.1)
     .progress { (bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite) in
        print("\(totalBytesWritten) / \(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)")
     }
      .responseJSON { response in
        print("RESPONSE \(response)")
      }
```

and the multi part implamention is

```
// this function creates the required URLRequestConvertible and NSData we need to use Alamofire.upload
func urlRequestWithComponents(urlString:String, parameters:Dictionary<String, String>, imageData:NSData) -> (URLRequestConvertible, NSData)
{
    // create url request to send
    let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)!)
    mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = Alamofire.Method.POST.rawValue
    let boundaryConstant = "myRandomBoundary12345";
    let contentType = "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundaryConstant
    mutableURLRequest.setValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    // create upload data to send
    let uploadData = NSMutableData()

    // add image
    uploadData.appendData("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    uploadData.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"file.png\"\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    uploadData.appendData("Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    uploadData.appendData(imageData)

    // add parameters
    for (key, value) in parameters {
        uploadData.appendData("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        uploadData.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n\(value)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
    }
    uploadData.appendData("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)--\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

    // return URLRequestConvertible and NSData
    return (Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: nil).0, uploadData)
}
```

now I'm sending the image and the parameters to the server and i got this error

> RESPONSE SUCCESS: {
>       Message = "The request entity's media type 'multipart/form-data' is not supported for this resource."; }

the server code is

```
[Route("api/files")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<Collection<AzureBlobInfo>> Post([FromBody] Groups parametersToSend)
{
    if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
    }
    // Get or create the blob container
    CloudBlobContainer container = await _blobContainer.Value;

    // Create a AzureBlobStorageMultipartProvider and process the request
    AzureBlobStorageMultipartProvider streamProvider = new AzureBlobStorageMultipartProvider(container, Path.GetTempPath());
    await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync<AzureBlobStorageMultipartProvider>(streamProvider);

    // Return result from storing content in the blob container
    return streamProvider.AzureBlobs;
}
```

the line             `if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent("form-data"))`
is alaways return true and I do not understand why

Comment: Your handler is expecting a Json request with a parameter type Groups but you're sending a file as multipart... that will not work, you can remove the parameter from the call (as you're not using it) and it will work.

Comment: wich part to change?

Comment: **public async Task<Collection<AzureBlobInfo>> Post([FromBody] Groups parametersToSend)** to **public async Task<Collection<AzureBlobInfo>> Post()**

Comment: still not good [Result]: FAILURE: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}

Comment: ok you right @Gusman  now i have another error

Comment: Create a new question with the new error.

Comment: // Get or create the blob container
            CloudBlobContainer container = await _blobContainer.Value;

            // Create a AzureBlobStorageMultipartProvider and process the request
            AzureBlobStorageMultipartProvider streamProvider = new AzureBlobStorageMultipartProvider(container, Path.GetTempPath());
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync<AzureBlobStorageMultipartProvider>(streamProvider);

            // Return result from storing content in the blob container
            return streamProvider.AzureBlobs;

Comment: the error that return   Message = "An error has occurred.";

Comment: i think my error is on the cloud blob container but i cant test it